# Using v-model with select as an external component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to create a selectbox component which has a predefined markup and is to be used everywhere in my system.
I'm experiencing difficulties with understanding the `v-model` property and how it can synchronize the predefined value coming from the parent component and the selectbox internal value.

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/60103/

I would like my root component to preselect a value, which the Selectbox component can change. My example works as expected but using the `$emit` event in the selectbox feels wrong the way I do it.

```js
const Selectbox = {
    props: {
        value: String
    },

    methods: {
        select($event, value) {
         // The example works but having
            // $event.target.value here seems very wrong
            this.$emit('input', $event.target.value);
        }
    },
    
    template: `
        <div>
            <select :value="value" @change="select($event, value)">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
            <div>The value is {{ value }}.</div>
        </div>`
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { Selectbox },
  data: () => ({
   selectboxValue: 1
  }),
  template: `
    <div>
        <selectbox v-model="selectboxValue" />
    </div>
  `
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: You're essentially doing it correctly. `v-model` is simply sugar for a `value` prop and a listener for the `input` event. [These can be customized](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model). I typically [use a computed](http://jsfiddle.net/buy3t5x4/) in the component, but what you have is fine as well.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in the comment above, you're essentially doing it right, but passing some arguments to the select method you don't really need. On the change event of the select element in your component, you don't really have to pass anything as the `event` object will automatically be passed if you just specify a function.

In your template:

```
<select :value="value" @change="select">
```

And your event handler:

```
select(evt) {
  this.$emit('input', evt.target.value);
}
```

```js
const Selectbox = {
    props: {
        value: String
    },

    methods: {
        select(evt) {
            this.$emit('input', evt.target.value);
        }
    },
    
    template: `
        <div>
            <select :value="value" @change="select">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
            <div>The value is {{ value }}.</div>
        </div>`
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { Selectbox },
  data: () => ({
   selectboxValue: 1
  }),
  template: `
    <div>
        <selectbox v-model="selectboxValue" />
    </div>
  `
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

What I typically like to do for input components like this, is simply use a computed property as the model for the component internally.

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

And a computed like this:

```
computed:{
  selected:{
    get() {return this.value},
    set(v) {this.$emit('input', v)}
  }
},
```

```js
const Selectbox = {
    props: {
        value: String
    },
    computed:{
     selected:{
       get() {return this.value},
        set(v) {this.$emit('input', v)}
      }
    },
    template: `
    <div>
        <select v-model="selected">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <div>The value is {{ value }}.</div>
    </div>`
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { Selectbox },
  data: () => ({
   selectboxValue: 1
  }),
  template: `
   <div>
     <selectbox v-model="selectboxValue" />
    </div>
  `
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: didn't saw the v-model, my bad

Comment: @DobleL No worries :)